# Passing variables? wordpress

Tags: variables, wordpress

Hello all I'm very thankful for this community here, wouldn't know what to do without you all.

First of all, I'm not even sure if the title to this post is accurate; please read on. In a nutshell what I'm trying to do in Wordpress is create a 'reply' button that will be displayed on the individual post's page. When someone clicks on this 'reply' button it will take them to a different WP page that is using a private messaging plugin. On this page I would like the 'to:' field to automatically know who to reply to (author of the post).

Now here's my question. Is this accomplished by "passing a variable" from first page to the second or is there another way to do this?

I'm not asking for specific code help so please don't tell me to go talk with the plugin developer. I'm just trying to get a general idea of how something like can be accomplished so that I can do some research myself.

At the very least, If someone get give me a starting point for me to do some google research that would be all I need. Being fairly new I don't even know what phrase I should be googling for.

Comment: you could pass variable on query string, ex: `yousite/formpage/?ref_id=x`. The `x` is what you want to pass. So you will need to put a link on the page which will point to the form page with the reference id. On form page, you can check the variable by name using `$_GET`, ex: `$_GET['ref_id']`. This is a simple PHP concept, and in WordPress there's no restriction to use that.

Comment: Shazzad, I thought wordpress doesn't allow data to be passed along the url? Is that different from what you are saying?

Comment: do you have any reference regarding "WordPress doesn't allow data" ? It's not different. You just have to make sure you are avoiding protected query strings as using them could create conflict.

Comment: Shazzad it's just stuff I've read online like this link below. Bear with me I might be misunderstanding this stuff. If so I would love some clarification. It's my understanding that you can't pass variables in the url for wordpress. ? http://www.webopius.com/content/137/using-custom-url-parameters-in-wordpress

Comment: Yes, u might have misunderstand the article. This is the [list of query arguments you can not use in url parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms). So you can pass anything else. You are passing query variable not to pass in WordPress Query, rather you are doing it for a custom purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that by implementing simple wp plugin. First of all you need to know that, there are lots of wp specific functions. You can use [the_content](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content) for putting your reply link after post content, and [get_author_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta) in order to get post's author email for putting it in your custom link. I know, you don't want to talk about code, but I can give you sample example; In order to apply this functionality on all post, you can simply implement a plugin.

**Edit:** For redirecting to [Private Messaging](http://wordpress.org/plugins/private-messages-for-wordpress/) plugin's send page with prepopulated recipient field, I have updated `get_the_author_meta('email')` with `get_the_author_meta('user_login')`. Now, you can go to mail send page, by clicking Reply link

add_filter('the_content', 'add_custom_link');
function add_custom_link($content) { // You can think that $content => individual post
    if(is_single()) {
        $content .= '

Reply to this post

';
    }
    return $content;
}

Save this code in a php file and zip it.Then, upload it to your wp site as plugin. And you will see your custom link at the end of your posts. Do not forget to update variables in plugin according to your needs(for example reply url domain)

Here is a working plugin demo: http://huseyinbabal.eu01.aws.af.cm/?p=1

Comment: @KaloyanIvanov thanks for your warning. I have also fixed another thing :)

Comment: I don't mind the code at all! I just said that because I don't want to be asking too much. Thank you now I'll have to sit down and study this. Wish me luck. I thought hacking together a site using WP was going to be easy but I've aged by 20 years. ;)

Comment: Ok, hope it helps. You can also see demo in my updated answer

Comment: Huseyin i've got a newbie question for you. So why is this done as a plugin and not putting it in a function.php of my child theme?

Comment: The answer is simple. What if, you want to do this operation on several wp sites? Is it easy for you edit functions.php, or simply upload this plugin with zero implementation? For those kind of things, I prefer developiing plugin. You can edit functions.php either. However, after some time, functions.php content becomes more complex and you may forgot which code does what job.

Comment: Huseyin so your solution is NOT using the "passing variable in url" solution? I think I'm getting confused with the other solutions posted here by others. Which one is better?

Comment: It is passing in url. And I developed it as plugin. .You can enable/disable this feature from plugin management easily. If you want, you can also put this function in your functions.php but in future, your code might be overrided while upgrading or something. You can use it any of your site.please try it and see how it works

Comment: Huseyin, installed and ran it. It looks great. I switched the 'email' to 'user_login' because (i think) that's what is need by the plugin I'm using. I do in fact see that it is passing the login from the url. Now on the receiving page, what do I need to change in order for the form to "receive" the user_login? Thanks again for your help. BTW the private message plugin I'm using is "private messages for wordpress".

Comment: May I see your demo page for this?

Comment: http://dev.bloomh.com/private-message/  but I believe you need to be logged in to wp to view it. For some reason unbeknownst to me, it gives me an error message when I logout.

Comment: In order to open private message page, you need to be logged in. So we need to check is_user_logged_in in our plugin. Am I right?

Comment: Ok, I found the solution. Please check my edited anser and update your plugin. Copy my code again and you can use my code directly. No need to change anything.

Comment: I've attached link to 2 items. One is screenshot to what the private message page looks like. Notice the recipient field has either a dropdown or autosuggest of every user. Instead I'm trying to have the recipient field autofilled after clicking your "reply" link. The second is the php code of the "send-page". What do I need to change in this page to have your passed variable "accepted" by this page? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12204373/screenshot-private-message.png   https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12204373/send-page.php

Comment: btw i have already tried your last solution in the past without success so I hope you can view my 2 links I just sent. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Create a form that posts to the secondary page.

- Use a hidden form field to pass the post ID
- Make sure you prefix the form fields so your $_POST variable doesn't conflict with any other core/plugin variables
- On the secondary page: make sure you sanitize that user input before you do anything else
  with it
- use the sanitized post id to look up the post's author, without
  having to expose the author's email in the url.

Your Form should look something like so:

```
<form action="url-of-page-2" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="myprefix_id" value="<?php echo get_the_ID();?>">
    <input type="submit" value="reply">
</form>
```

Comment: Matt...very interesting. I'm a newbie and having difficulty grasping how to execute what you just said, however I get the overall sensibility of your solution. I sense the "hidden form field" might be an awesome thing. Do you care to unpack this a little more?

Comment: Yeah, I just mean pass it as a hidden input in the form tag.

<input type="hidden" name="myprefix_id" value="<?php echo get_the_ID();?>">

Comment: Matt I'm trying to do what you suggested. Any further explanation on how to "sanitize" user input?

Comment: Take a look here: 
http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

and
http://us3.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php